# Expansion of this expression

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Let $x$ be a real number in $\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right].$ It is well known that 
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} x^n.$$
What is the expansion or the series of the expression $(\frac{1}{1-x})^2$?
Many thanks.

Comment: $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \frac{1}{1-2x+x^2} = \frac{1}{1-(2x-x^2)}$. Now can you maybe find a substitution?

Comment: If a power series in $x$ converges  for $|x|<A$ with $A>0$ you can differentiate it term-by-term  for $|x|<A$ to get the derivative of the sum.  Isaac Newton did this all the time and likely thought it was obvious. Maybe it was for him.

Comment: I have a confusion, if $x=0$, then the $1=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}0^n$, then the first term i.e. $0^0=undefined$.Then this case will not be considered.If I am wrong then please do correct me.Thanking in anticipation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Method 1 : Binomial Theorem for any index**

$$(1-x)^{-n}= 1+nx+ \frac{n(n+1)}{2!}x^2+ \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3!}x^3 \dots $$

Putting $n=1$ , we get :

$$\frac{1}{1-x} = 1+x+x^2+x^3+ \dots $$

Putting $n=2$ , we get :

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = 1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+ \dots $$

**Method 2 : Derivatives**

Let: $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x} = 1+x+x^2+x^3+ \dots $$

Take derivative w.r.t. $x$ both the sides;
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = 1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+ \dots $$

$$ \implies \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = 1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+ \dots $$

*NOTE :* These expansions are valid not only for $ x \in \left[0,\dfrac{1}{2}\right]$ but $\forall ~x \in (-1,1)$

Answer (score 3):

By the Cauchy product,

$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n\right)^2=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n\right)\left(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} x^m\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}x^nx^m=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^k x^k=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)x^k.$$

Comment: How did you get last step : $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^n x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n$$

Comment: The inner term does not depend on $m$.

Answer (score 2):

Given that $$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$$ for all $x\in(-1,1)$, we may differentiate both sides to obtain
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n$$
for all $x\in(-1,1)$.

Here we have used the fact that a power series is differentiable inside it's interval of convergence, and the derivative can be obtained by differentiating term-by-term, just as you would for a polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

Or do by brute force multiplication and gathering terms:
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=$$
$$
(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\ldots)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\ldots)\\
=(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\ldots)\\
+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\ldots\\
\quad +x^2+x^3+x^4+\ldots\\
\quad \quad +x^3+x^4+\ldots\\
=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\ldots
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you consider $$1+2x+3x^2\ldots \infty,$$ then it is $\dfrac{1}{{(1-x)^2}}$.

Proof: Let $S=1+2x+3x^2\ldots \infty \Rightarrow Sx=x+2x^2+3x^3\ldots\infty$
Now, $S-Sx=1+x+x^2\ldots\infty=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\dfrac{1}{1-x}$

$$S(1-x)=\dfrac{1}{1-x} \Rightarrow S=\dfrac{1}{{(1-x)^2}}.$$

$\therefore$ The series of the expansion is $S=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x=\dfrac{1}{{(1-x)^2}}$, where $|x|<1$.
This is just the Generating Functions.